# Do I need to use parentheses everytime I reference a casted object?

Tags: java

I am following the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html) on Java.
In the chapter about “Using an Interface as a Type” there is the following piece of code.

```java
public Object findLargest(Object object1, Object object2) {
     Relatable obj1 = (Relatable)object1;
     Relatable obj2 = (Relatable)object2;
     if ((obj1).isLargerThan(obj2) > 0)
         return object1;
     else
         return object2;
     }
}
```

I think I understand the 2nd and 3rd line: I am casting object1 (object2 respectively) into a `Relatable` type, and I am giving the name “obj1” (obj2 resp.) to this label.

It is the very next line that I do not understand:

> Why (obj1) with parentheses, and not simply without?

A post on the same piece of code says that one needs to properly cast the object with parentheses. However

1. isn’t that what was already done in the 2nd and 3rd line?
2. In addition, if that really was the case, then why `isLargerThan(obj2)` and not `isLargerThan((obj2))`?

Comment: Try it out. I'm pretty sure you don't need those additional parentheses. (However, if you were to cast `obj1` in the same line, you would need them to make clear that the cast happens first)

Comment: Can you give a URL link to the tutorial? Maybe there is some context that would explain. However, looking at the piece of code you posted by itself, there is no need to put obj1 in parentheses.

Comment: @k314159 [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html)

Comment: Looking at the tutorial, there is no reason for obj1 to be parenthesised at all. You would only need parentheses if it was an expression, as in `int length = (string1 + string2).length();`

Comment: Tried a bit on finding some way to submit ticket to update the tutorial, but with no success. If anyone know how to do it, please help. It will be helpful for java beginner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parentheses around `obj1` are not needed. However, they are not syntactically wrong.

However, if you would do the cast inline, you would need the parentheses, i. e.

```java
public Object findLargest(Object object1, Object object2) {
    if (((Relatable)object1).isLargerThan((Relatable)object2) > 0)
        return object1;
    else
        return object2;
}
```

would be the code equivalent to your code. And now, you need the parentheses around `(Relatable)object2`, as the dot before the `isLargerThan` has higher precedence than the cast operator. See e. g [this operator precedence table](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/): cast is on level 13, while the dot for member access has the highest precedence (level 16).